# Rails + Prawn: undefined method `table' for #<Prawn::Document:0x007fda2d594a98>:

Tags: prawn

I'm using Rails 4 + prawn_rails + the latest version of prawn (v 1.1.0) and I noticed in the changelog here: https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/wiki/CHANGELOG that tables are now separated.

I followed the instructions to `require "prawn/tables"`. I did this by adding a file in my `lib` directory:

lib/prawn.rb

```
require "prawn/tables"
```

I restarted my rails server and I still get the error:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `table' for #<Prawn::Document:0x007fda2d594a98>:
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: it's prawn/table, not prawn/tables

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You should add these lines into your Gemfile.

```
gem 'prawn', '~> 1.2.1'
gem 'prawn-table', '~> 0.1.0'
```

Comment: If you're using `Bundler.require` (such as in a Rails app), the gems need to be listed in **this exact order**.  Otherwise you may get this error on startup: `undefined method 'extensions' for Prawn::Document:Class`

Comment: you can do 'prawn-table', '~> 0.2.0' now.

Answer (score 13):

The line in the documentation is WRONG. add `require 'prawn/table'`
 to your .pdf.prawn file on the top and it will work.

Comment: thank you ! any ideas where this pdf.prawn file is located?